# How do you build a networkx visualization from dataframe with groups (nodes) and values (edges)?

Tags: python, networkx

If I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group' : ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
                      'value' : ['green', 'blue', 'orange', 'pink', 'green', 'green', 'black', 'yellow', 
                                 'green','pink','yellow']})
```

How would I clean the data in order to build a `networkx` visualization showing the `df['group']` values as 'nodes' while the number of common `df['value']` values determines the thickness of the connection between nodes?

Comment: "_...the number of common `df['value']` values determines the thickness of the connection between nodes..._" is a bit ambiguous depending on how you count common values.  In your example data, what would the expected weight of the edge be be between the `'A'` and `'B'` nodes?

Comment: Also not clear if self loops are allowed.  Is the graph directed or undirected?

Comment: Yea, I'm not interested in self loops or a directed graph. And I tried to use dummy data (which is sometimes tricky), but I would say the weight of the edge between 'A' and 'B' nodes is 2 (I think I counted correctly) which represents the unique common edges. But the answer below is helpful (I had a nice visualization in Bokeh, but was struggling with ways to represent edge weight and this helped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you mean the simplest case: undirected graph, no self-loops, counting only unique colors that appear as a `value` for each `group`.

I'll change this answer if you indicate otherwise in the comments above.

```
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx


d = df.groupby('group').agg({'value': lambda x: x.tolist()}).to_dict()['value']

combos = list(combinations(d.keys(), 2))
edge_lst = [(combo[0],
          combo[1],
          len(set(d[combo[0]]) & set(d[combo[1]])))
         for combo in combos if len(set(d[combo[0]]) & set(d[combo[1]])) > 0]

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(d)
g.add_weighted_edges_from(edge_lst)
```

gives `g.nodes()` as

```
NodeView(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```

and `g.edges(data=True)` as

```
EdgeDataView([('A', 'B', {'weight': 2})])
```

If you want to do a very simple visualization with `edge_width` proportional to the weight of the edge:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
edgewidth = [g[u][v]['weight'] for u, v in g.edges()]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, width=edgewidth)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos)
plt.show()
```

gives
[image: network_viz]